# Shinytest2 json comparisons fail because of renderUI div IDs

Tags: r, shiny, renderui, shinytest

I am using R Shiny's shinytest2 package to automate testing my app. The app and tests work. However, the tests keep failing shinytest2's comparisons because of `renderUI()`'s auto-generated  ids, e.g. *out63cdc91c431ff1ea*. I thought setting the driver's `seed` would suffice, as it worked when I used `shinytest`, but it doesn't.

Here's a pared-down version of my test script:

```
library(shinytest2)
test_that("{shinytest2} recording: test-good", {
    print("Running test-good")
    app <- AppDriver$new(
        variant = platform_variant(), 
        name = "test-good", 
        seed = 1234,
        load_timeout = 1e+05)

app$set_inputs(sidebarmenuid = "tabClientCount")
app$wait_for_idle(500) #wait until whole application is idle for 500ms
app$expect_values()
})
```

And here's some of the console failure:

```
Failure (test-good.R:20:1): {shinytest2} recording: test-good
Snapshot of `file` to 'good/test-good-001.json' has changed
```

So in good/test-good-001.json the ID is *out63cdc91c431ff1ea* and in good/test-good-001.new.json the ID is *outcdc91c431ff1ea2a*. And if I run it again, the IDs change again. I thought the random seed would work, but it's not. How can I stop these renderUI-auto-generated IDs from flagging failures, e.g. via an option to ignore these sorts of IDs, or via setting the ids myself. Also, I have many tests, so the solution needs to be scalable.

In case the renderUI code is helpful:

```
headerGeneric <- function(tabTitle, extraHTML = NULL) {
  renderUI({
    if(valid_file() == 1) {
      list(h2(tabTitle),
           h4(strong("Date Range of Current File: "),
            paste(
             format(Project0$start_date, "%m-%d-%Y"),
             "to",
             format(Project0$end_date, "%m-%d-%Y")
           )),
           extraHTML
      )
    } else {
      h4("This is blank until your data has been validated.")
    }
  })
}

output$headerClientCounts <- headerGeneric("Client Counts Report", 
    renderUI({   
      organization <- Project0 %>%
        filter(ProjectName == input$currentProviderList) %>%
        pull(OrganizationName)

      h4(organization, "|", input$currentProviderList)
    })
  )
```

UPDATE: The source of the problem was the nested-nature of the `renderUI()` code. This must be because each `renderUI()` call is essentially creating a new reactive context, and so it generates a new ID. `shinytest2`'s seed must only apply to the outer-most `renderUI()`. But I'm not sure how best to avoid this. I created the `headerGeneric()` function, because we reuse the main part of it over and over on each tab of our app. Is there a way to pass in a hard-coded ID to `renderUI()`?

Comment: I don't understand why you need 2 `renderUI` calls, why not simply returning the HTML and using the `render` only when assigning it to `output`?

Comment: I *think* because both inner and outer `renderUI`s involve inputs. It's not just static HTML. The users upload a data file and the app runs and displays data quality checks. Project0 comes from the input file. My understanding is that `renderUI` is required when you have dynamic output like this.

Comment: Nope, `render*` does what the name says, it renders stuff. It is perfectly valid to have a function which returns `HTML` and in your `render` function you call this `HTML` returning function. As a rule of thumb, you most likely will need `render` only next to `output$some_id` .

Comment: Are you saying that the function returning HTML can include inputs? So if I change the input value, the function will automatically and dynamically return the updated HTML?

Comment: well it is a function so you can pass what ever you like. if you access reactives make sure it is in a reactive friendly environment. If you ask anew question , I can happily provide some code (too little place here)

Comment: Given that the code is working now, I probably will leave it at that. but if you post an answer I'll try it out and upvote it if it works

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was the nested-nature of the renderUI code. It looks like I should be attaching all `renderUI()`s to `output`s (whose names become the IDs), but, if I don't, Shiny is "smart" enough to generate a random ID for me. I do think this was not a problem with shinytest, but once I associated the inner `renderUI()` with an output, that fixed the problem.